# Ncurses 6.0 Compilation Error - error: expected ')' before 'int'

Tags: ncurses

## Problem description

Trying to install ncurses 6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is failing with a compilation error:

```
In file included from ./curses.priv.h:325:0,
                 from ../ncurses/lib_gen.c:19:
_24273.c:843:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
../include/curses.h:1631:56: note: in definition of macro ‘mouse_trafo’
#define mouse_trafo(y,x,to_screen) wmouse_trafo(stdscr,y,x,to_screen)
                                                    ^
Makefile:962: recipe for target '../objects/lib_gen.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../objects/lib_gen.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/netsamir/Sofware/Tmux/ncurses-6.0/ncurses'
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

## Configuration

```
netsamir@octopus:~/Sofware/Tmux/ncurses-6.0$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

netsamir@octopus:~/Sofware/Tmux/ncurses-6.0$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

netsamir@octopus:~/Sofware/Tmux/ncurses-6.0$ cpp --version
cpp (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: This was [reported](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2015-08/msg00011.html) and [fixed](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2015-08/msg00013.html) on the *bug-ncurses* mailing list several months before.  The problem was Debian's version of mawk.

Comment: Thomas Dickey's answer actually led to a fix for me, unlike the accepted answer to OP. I simply hacked [the fix](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2015-08/msg00013.html) by editing `MKlib_gen.sh` such that `PRG=gcc` in place of the subshell involving `awk`.

Answer (score 40):

## Solution

Export the variable CPPFLAGS in the shell with -P as follow

```
netsamir@octopus:~/$ export CPPFLAGS="-P"
```

## Reference

http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/19762

Comment: do this before configuring

Comment: It can also be added to the configure command so it only has temporary effect. Example: ./configure <options> CPPFLAGS="-P"

Comment: @JohnMudd, well then there's also `CPPFLAGS=-P ./configure`, but that relies on  having a particular shell. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`$ export CPPFLAGS="-P"`
This works for my local install of ncurses 6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as well.

Comment: Thanks, TheDude. I was looking for the documentation for code highlights.